# about bundle install with svn source path for rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

we can use :git=>'git path'来bundle install gem,
but how to use them from a svn path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundler 1.0 only supports Git repositories, so I'm afraid you can't tie your Gemfile to a Subversion repository.